# How to change the cursor from One textbox to another

Tags: vb.net

I have Two text Boxes named Text1,text2.Once I finished the value input into Text1 I would like to move the cursor automatically to Tex2.I don't like to put a maximum length for Text1,
The valued finished indication I would like in Text1 is Mouse click out of Text1.

Please help me to code it in vb.net

Comment: Do you mean the cursor (mouse pointer) or the caret?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set focus to the `textbox2` on `textbo1's` **lost focus event**

```
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus
    TextBox2.Focus()
End Sub
```

or in other ways :

in form load put the code like this :

```
    TextBox1.TabIndex = 0
    TextBox2.TabIndex = 1
```

[Reference:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

**GotFocus**   :Occurs when the control receives focus (occur when Cursor inside the textbox)

**LostFocus**  :Occurs when the control loses focus(occur when Cursor leaves thetext box)

then simply you can redirect to the `textbox2` from `textbox1` by clicking the `tab` key

Comment: You need to add how `textbox1 or textbox2` is going to loose its focus.

Comment: Your suggestion isn't particularly clear, though. I would suggest setting up the tabbing behaviour as given here, rather than forcing your users to interact with the form in a specific way.